# How to change the text of Next and Back Button of the property sheet?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I need to change the text of "Next" and "Back" button of a property sheet .I tried doing it as follows but the text didn't change.

```
CPropertySheet *m_mySheet = (CPropertySheet*)GetParent();
::SetDlgItemTextW((HWND)m_mySheet,ID_WIZNEXT,L"Validate");
```

The above text I placed in the OnInitDialog of a propertypage just to verify whether the text is changing or not .

Can anyone please let me know how can I change the text and also let me know where I need to place the code .

Comment: You can't cast a `CPropertySheet*` to `HWND` directly. Use `m_mySheet->GetSafeHWnd()` or `(HWND)*m_mySheet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
::SetDlgItemTextW((HWND)*m_mySheet,ID_WIZNEXT,L"Validate");
```

Replacing with above piece of line changed the Text of the Next button.